# PHP: file_exist errors preventing show entire page

Tags: php, image, file-exists

I got an error when handling a not seated avatar image, `0.jpg` is a default user avatar and every user had an avatar called `firstname_lastname.jpg`

```
<?php  
$uname_ = 'John_Doe';  
$avname = "media/avatars/" . $uname_ . '.jpg';
  if(file_exists($avname) { 
    $avatar = $uname_ ;
  } else { 
    $avatar = "0" ;
  }
?>
<img src="media/avatars/<?php echo $avatar ?>.jpg">
```

This does't work, and is preventing the page to show. I get a blank response.

Comment: use full path in the url

Comment: You should start to monitor your http servers error log file. That is where you can actually read what the issue is instead of having to _guess_.

Comment: missed a closing brace after file_exists..

Comment: @arkascha i've tried using `error_reporting(E_ALL);` but nothing changed, the shown page is blank and no error is displayed

Comment: That has nothing to do with looking into your log file, does it?

Comment: nope.. everything alright.. you just need to add up a closing brace after file_exists.. which you are missing here in your code..

Comment: @ameenulla0007 damn, thanks! now the page is shown as expected, damned stupid error!

Comment: Do you want to write a question here for each and every minor error you accidentally implement? You simply _cannot_ program php without access to that log file.

Comment: the problem now is that i get the 0.jpg image even if the proper user avatar exist

Comment: yup.. happens some times.. :) silly things make much difference.. :) @andreaem

Comment: @arkascha you're right, but error_reporting was not showing errors (don't know why) and was thinking there was another type of error. Thank you guys so mutch

Comment: Once more: `error_reporting` and the error log file are two different things.

Comment: @arkascha i haven't no php_errors.log created in this dir, only one in the root but does not contain anything related to this

Comment: The error log file is configured in your http server configuration. There can be only one log file, not multiple. If your error log file does not contain a mentioning of above syntax error then most likely you are looking at the wrong file. Or you have turned off all error logging which is not very likely. You want to solve that issue, since you certainly will have to solve syntax error in future :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you got this

```
if(file_exists($avname) {
```

need this

```
if(file_exists($avname)) {
```